# Wordpress rewrite subdomain as category

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, categories

In a WP single install, my category page url looks like this: **domain.com/news/austin/central-austin/**

Added a subdomain (forwarding with masking), so now if you visit **central-austin.domain.com** it will display the corresponding category page.

The missing part is if you try to access a post under the category, it will display the original url path: **domain.com/austin/central-austin/hotel-breaks-ground/**

How can I get the subdomain path for all single stories like: **central-austin.domain.com/austin/hotel-breaks-ground/**

Not a lot of experience in rewrite rules, any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: That is not an issue of rewriting, but of what URLs WordPress outputs. Look into filters such as https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_link and https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink